# FlywayDB not creating extension

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, flyway

I have this startup script which is picked up by FlywayDB:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
-- clean up
DROP table IF EXISTS tenants;

-- create table
CREATE TABLE tenants (
    id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(), name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
);
```

and my spring boot config:

```
#FLYWAY
spring.flyway.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/tenant?currentSchema=public
spring.flyway.user=postgres
spring.flyway.password=secret
spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true
```

All my scripts are working fine except for "CREATE EXTENTION" bit.
I can log in the DB with the same credentials and run it manually with success. But via FlyWay: No Way. Wonder why

Comment: Only a superuser is allowed to create extensions. Are you running your Flyway script as a superuser?

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: No error: just the extension wasn't created. I will dig more around. I believe it's a permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

This should work just fine and is widely used. Make sure your user has the necessary permissions to do so.

Answer (score 0):

> Loading an extension requires the same privileges that would be
>   required to create its component objects. For most extensions this
>   means superuser or database owner privileges are needed. The user who
>   runs CREATE EXTENSION becomes the owner of the extension for purposes
>   of later privilege checks, as well as the owner of any objects created
>   by the extension's script.

read docs: [CREATE EXTENSION](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createextension.html)

Comment: in my dockerfile I am using this user: postgresql with password: secret. I used the same one to create the "database". But when it comes to this extension .. something I am missing